# select all - click event interferes with function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have buttons that I transform to check boxes. On click of the button I just change the icon to a check mark and the background. I have a hidden checkbox right following the button tag which gets updated as the button gets clicked.

The issue I face is that when I click "Select All", the btn and icon class of that element does not toggle.

It is somewhat complicated to explain, the issue is a lot easier understood when demonstrated:

```
<span class="button-checkbox">
    <button id="select-all" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default"><i class="state-icon fa fa-square-o"></i> Select all?</button>
    <input type="checkbox" />
</span>

<br>

<span class="button-checkbox">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default btn-private"><i class="state-icon fa fa-square-o"></i></button>
    <input name="{%=file.name%}" type="checkbox" />
</span>

<span class="button-checkbox">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default btn-private"><i class="state-icon fa fa-square-o"></i></button>
    <input name="{%=file.name%}" type="checkbox" />
</span>
```

and this is the jQuery code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-private', function(event) {
    var $btn = $(this);
    var $span = $btn.closest('.button-checkbox'); // find the span that surrounds the button/icon/input
    var $icon = $btn.find('.state-icon');  // find the icon
    var $checkbox = $span.find('input');
    var wasChecked = $checkbox.prop('checked');
    $icon.toggleClass('fa-square-o fa-check-square-o');
    $btn.toggleClass('btn-default btn-white');
    $checkbox.prop('checked', !wasChecked);
});

// Listen for click on toggle checkbox
$(document).on('click', '#select-all', function(event) {

    var $btn = $(this);
    var $span = $btn.closest('.button-checkbox'); // find the span that surrounds the button/icon/input
    var $icon = $btn.find('.state-icon');  // find the icon
    var $checkbox = $span.find('input');
    var wasChecked = $checkbox.prop('checked');

    $icon.toggleClass('fa-square-o fa-check-square-o');
    $btn.toggleClass('btn-default btn-white');

    $checkbox.prop('checked', !wasChecked);
    if(!wasChecked) {
        // Iterate each checkbox
        $(':checkbox').each(function() {
            this.checked = true;
            var $btn = $(this).prev();
            var $icon = $btn.find('.state-icon');
            $btn.toggleClass('btn-default btn-white');
            $icon.toggleClass('fa-square-o fa-check-square-o');
        });
    }
    else {
        $(':checkbox').each(function() {
            this.checked = false;
            var $btn = $(this).prev();
            var $icon = $btn.find('.state-icon');
            $btn.toggleClass('btn-white btn-default');
            $icon.toggleClass('fa-check-square-o fa-square-o');

        });
    }
});
```

This obviously looks like a lot of code to understand what's going on. I created a jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/gj6bmt93/1/

When I click "Select All", I would like that check mark and the background color to be toggled as well. At the moment it does not change, but everything else works the way it is supposed to.

Thanks so much for looking into this issue and questions of mine! I truly appreciate any help.

edit1:
I forgot to mention that all the check boxes other than the select all one, get added to the page after the site was loaded. So I believe I have to use $(document).

Comment: what you can do is when you click selectAll, clear previous selection and then apply either selecting all or deselecting all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is after toggling the button/checkbox of select all you then re-toggle them in the loop below

```
$icon.toggleClass('fa-square-o fa-check-square-o'); //<---- Select all toggled here
$btn.toggleClass('btn-default btn-white'); //<---- Select all toggled here

// Iterate each checkbox
$(':checkbox').each(function() {
    this.checked = true;
    var $btn = $(this).prev();
    var $icon = $btn.find('.state-icon');
    $btn.toggleClass('btn-default btn-white');<---- // All buttons(including select all re-toggled here)
    $icon.toggleClass('fa-square-o fa-check-square-o');<---- // All checkboxes(including select all re-toggled here)
});
```

The last two lines re-toggles the state of all the checkboxes including the Select All button/checkbox

Simply remove the two lines before the start of the checkbox iteration and let the loop handle checking and unchecking all buttons/checkboxes

```
//$icon.toggleClass('fa-square-o fa-check-square-o');
//$btn.toggleClass('btn-default btn-white');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gj6bmt93/3/

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not solve the issue either. :-( I need all checkboxes checked. The ones inside the button, too, as well as its background color. But I agree, it probablt is due to the fact that it retoggles the select all as well. I just don't know how to fix it

Comment: Just remove the 2 lines I said and it works, check my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gj6bmt93/3/

Comment: Oh wow! That works! Thank you so much. Now, the only issue I still face, is that if I manually select a check box button and then press select all, it seems to be off. Any pointers to that solution? Thanks again for getting me this far!

Comment: @ChrisPalmerBreuer Just looked at this.. check this fiddle, hope the comments help :) https://jsfiddle.net/gj6bmt93/5/

Comment: You are amazing! You can't believe how much time I put into this!! Thanks :-)